# Are weakly compact sets bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space, and let $X'$ denote its topological dual, that is, the vector space of all continuous linear functionals on $X$.
If $A$ is a weakly compact subset of $X$, that is, if $A$ is $\sigma(X,X')$-compact in $X$, is it (always) true that $A$ is bounded in $X$ ?

If not, can anybody give a counterexample for such a set?

Comment: They certainly are in normed linear spaces. Without the Hausdorff condition, they need not be. I don't know in general though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a locally convex Hausdorff space all weakly bounded sets are bounded. In particular, weakly compact sets are bounded.

That weakly bounded sets are bounded is stated, e.g., in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, Theorem 3.18. The proof is a nice application of the uniform boundedness principle: If $B\subseteq X$ is weakly bounded and $p$ is a continuous seminorm on $X$, then $X^*_p=\{f\in X^*: p^*(f)<\infty \}$ endowed with the dual norm $p^*(f)=\sup\{|f(x)|: p(x)\le 1\}$ is a Banach space. For every $x\in B$ the evaluation $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ is linear and continuous on $X_p^*$ and $\{\delta_x: x\in B\}$ is pointwise bounded because $B$ is weakly bounded. Hence, by the uniform boundedness principle,  $\sup\{|\delta_x(f)|: x\in B, p^*(f)\le 1\} =c<\infty$ and then Hahn-Banach implies $\sup\{p(x): x\in B\}\le c$, i.e., $B$ is bounded in $X$.